# Calculating time-varying frequency and phase angle from a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, time-series, fft

I have data from a number of high frequency data capture devices connected to generators on an electricity grid.  These meters collect data in ~1 second "bursts" at ~**1.25ms** frequency, ie. fast enough to actually see the waveform. See below graphs showing voltage and current for the three phases shown in different colours.

This timeseries has a *changing fundamental frequency*, ie the frequency of the electricity grid is changing over the length of the timeseries.  I want to roll this (messy) waveform data up to summary statistics of **frequency** and **phase angle** for each phase, calculated/estimated every **20ms** (approx once per cycle).

1. The simplest way that I can think of would be to just count the gap between the 0 passes (y=0) on each wave and use the offset to calculate phase angle. Is there a neat way to achieve this (ie. a table of interpolated x values for which y=0).
2. However the above may be quite noisy, and I was wondering if there is a more mathematically elegant way of estimating a changing frequency and phase angle with pandas/scipy etc. I know there are some sophisticated techniques available for periodic functions but I'm not familiar enough with them. Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

[image]

[image]

Here's a "toy" data set of the first few waves as a pandas Series:

```
import pandas as pd, datetime as dt
ds_waveform = pd.Series(
index = pd.date_range('2020-08-23 12:35:37.017625', '2020-08-23 12:35:37.142212890', periods=100),
data = [  -9982., -110097., -113600.,  -91812.,  -48691.,  -17532.,
         24452.,   75533.,  103644.,  110967.,  114652.,   92864.,
         49697.,   18402.,  -23309.,  -74481., -103047., -110461.,
       -113964.,  -92130.,  -49373.,  -18351.,   24042.,   75033.,
        103644.,  111286.,  115061.,   81628.,   61614.,   19039.,
        -34408.,  -62428., -103002., -110734., -114237.,  -92858.,
        -49919.,  -19124.,   23542.,   74987.,  103644.,  111877.,
        115379.,   82720.,   62251.,   19949.,  -33953.,  -62382.,
       -102820., -111053., -114555.,  -81941.,  -62564.,  -19579.,
         34459.,   62706.,  103325.,  111877.,  115698.,   83084.,
         62888.,   20949.,  -33362.,  -61791., -102547., -111053.,
       -114919.,  -82805.,  -62882.,  -20261.,   33777.,   62479.,
        103189.,  112195.,  116380.,   83630.,   63843.,   21586.,
        -32543.,  -61427., -102410., -111553., -115374.,  -83442.,
        -63565.,  -21217.,   33276.,   62024.,  103007.,  112468.,
        116471.,   84631.,   64707.,   22405.,  -31952.,  -61108.,
       -101955., -111780., -115647.,  -84261.])
```

Comment: Perhaps some Fourier analysis and the functions from [`scipy.signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) could be useful.

Comment: I suggest you feed a sine curve signal of known freq into a FFT call then make sense of the output of that call ..  that will take some time as the magic of Fourier Transforms is non trivial .. bonus points once you have that working is to do the miraculous .. start with time-series data (in time domain) --> FFT call  ( now same data is in freq domain )  -->  inverse FFT call ( now you get back your original time domain signal )  .. do that sequence of two conversions and verify the final output is the same (to a first approximation) as the original input time-series data

Comment: bonus points for you to accomplish that without having to ask any questions ... this site has this type of question covered in spades just look for those answers ... its much more productive to do research than waiting for a question to get answered (possibly incorrectly) ... have fun